# AS3: How do I definitively smooth a bitmap image loaded from an outside server

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

This issue has been following me around for almost a year now, and I want to kill it, for my sake and for the sake of all.

I'm working on some banner ads that need to load in images from a client's site for display. When I tried to do this using AS2, I found out that AS2 doesn't let you do that. It's a bug in the language. There are workarounds for images on the local server, but images loaded from are not allowed to share their BitmapData, so those workarounds don't work. I ended up capitulating after about two months of banging my head against the desk and cursing Macromedia.

Now we are talking about moving to AS3 (finally) and I'm really excited. Or, I was really excited until I started doing some tests for image quality and found that there is very little change in image quality happening here. It's a repeat of my trials with AS2: everything loads perfectly in the IDE, I get all excited, I move the swfs over to the test server to run them online, and POOF - jaggies. Jaggies everywhere.

I've read a number of solutions online, none of which work. They include:

- Setting target.content.smoothing to "true". Works great in the IDE. All improvements disappear in the browser.
- Setting target.scaleX = target.scaleY to 1.01. It just breaks the swf.
- Adding "new LoaderContext(true)" to my parameters for the load command. Does nothing.
- Setting target.content.pixelSnapping to "always". Looks perfect in the IDE, not in the browser.
- Setting a crossdomain.xml file. The images are showing up - they're being loaded, even if jaggedly, so there must be a functioning crossdomain file on the client's server, right?

So now I'm just stuck, and brokenhearted. Could anyone offer insight on my code, and why it might not be rendering as beautifully as it should be? Here is the client-safe version of the quick demo I am making (only the image URL has been deleted, everything else is as it is now):

```
import flash.events.Event;

function completeHandler(e:Event) {
    e.target.content.pixelSnapping = "always"; 
    e.target.content.smoothing = true;
}

var imgurl:String = "CLIENT'S IMAGE URL HERE";

var imageLoader01:Loader = new Loader();
var image01:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imgurl);
imageLoader01.load(image01);
imageLoader01.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
addChild(imageLoader01);
imageLoader01.x = 2;
imageLoader01.y = 0;
imageLoader01.scaleX = imageLoader01.scaleY = .6;

var imageLoader02:Loader = new Loader();
var image02:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imgurl);
imageLoader02.load(image02);
imageLoader02.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
addChild(imageLoader02);
imageLoader02.x = 100;
imageLoader02.y = 80;
imageLoader02.scaleX = imageLoader02.scaleY = .308;

var imageLoader03:Loader = new Loader();
var image03:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imgurl);
imageLoader03.load(image03);
imageLoader03.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
addChild(imageLoader03);
imageLoader03.x = 200;
imageLoader03.y = 180;
imageLoader03.scaleX = imageLoader03.scaleY = .152;

var bannerLegend:legend = new legend(); 
addChild(bannerLegend);
```

Thank you very much in advance. Any help will be sorely appreciated.

Update: Here is the HTML embed code:

```
<div id="swf_mr_sc_wt_si"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var swfurl = "http://DOMAIN_WITHELD_SORRY/static/AS3.swf?m=DEFAULT&t=" + (new Date().getTime());
swfobject.embedSWF(swfurl, "swf_mr_sc_wt_si", 300, 250, "8.0.0", "");
// -->
</script>

<p>
```

Hope this helps.

Further Update: We are not listed in the crossdomain.xml file. But we can still load the jagged images. And those images, when loaded into the same swf run in the IDE, are smooth. I think I'm missing understanding of some kind of apocryphal knowledge here, because everything I read points to me being able to do this. This is VERY confusing.

Comment: Check your FP version at the very least, check at another PC, check in another browser (IE vs FF vs Chrome, maybe vs Opera or other browsers too). All this everywhere? Also, what are "jaggies"? Ladders in lines? No antialiasing? Check also if `stage.quality` is `"high"`, perhaps there's autoassigned value which gets lowered by some setting.

Comment: Thanks Vesper! By "jaggies," I meant no antialiasing. Everything is antialiased correctly in the IDE, but in the browser? Nothing. I tested it out in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9. Don't have access to another PC at the moment, but my Player is at 11.8.800.129.

If there were an autoassigned value that gets reassigned, would it only get reassigned in the browser, not in the IDE?

Comment: Yes, it might get assigned a different value in browser's FP than in debugger FP.

Comment: Please post the HTML embed code as well. Thanks.

Comment: Added the HTML embed code. Thanks!

@Vesper: what could I look for that might be getting reassigned? Would it be something visible in the script window of the IDE?

Also: I just checked the crossdomain.xml of the site that some of the images are coming from and we're not listed in it. Could it be that the crossdomain is allowing loading images but not allowing smoothing?

Comment: Considering applying a blur filter to like 0.1. Also you won't get any such problems if you are using only vector graphics. Which you should.

Comment: The crossdomain has nothing do to with the smoothing.
I made an example that workes for me. Does this have the same smoothing problem on your machine? http://sorinvasilescu.ro/kitten/

Comment: Thanks Discipol. Unfortunately, when I apply a blur, I just get blurry jagged lines. It doesn't seem to spur the Player into any extra processing. And there are times when you need to work with bitmap data in Flash. This is one of those times.

Comment: @evilpenguin: Thank you! And, no, it renders beautifully on my machine. Could you send me the image URL you used? I'll plug it into my code and check.

Comment: URL is http://sorinvasilescu.ro/kitten/kitten.jpg
I'll leave it there for a few days. Check my answer, though.

Comment: Scratch that, check out Strille's answer, he actually nailed it. And it was in fact related to the image being on another domain..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the image you're loading is located on another domain, and that domain's crossdomain.xml does not contain the domain the .swf is residing on, basically giving the .swf "permission" to access the image's pixel data (Yes, just enabling smoothing on an image loaded from another domain requires the same security as when reading the pixel data using BitmapData.draw(), which is a bit curious). When running in local security sandbox the restrictions are more lax, that's why it works running from the IDE.

Even if your domain *were* among the approved domains in the crossdomain.xml you might need to tell the Flash Player to check the policy file by sending in `new LoaderContext(true)` as a second argument to `Loader.load()` when loading the image.

**Edit:** I originally thought using loadBytes() would be a workaround, but it turns out it's not. I have removed that example code

Comment: That is very high on the list of the dumbest things I've heard a programming language do.. But it checks out, this code works perfectly and does not trigger any security sandbox violations, while the other one does..

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this example. There is only one thing: the image in your example comes from a server with this setting in its crossdomain.xml file: <allow-access-from domain="*"/> The servers I have to work with aren't allowing all domains. Is there a workaround for when the crossdomain file doesn't include you? Or am I screwed here? Thanks.

Comment: Doh! Yes, you are completely right, the example I did use had the least restrictive crossdomain possible. Turns out loadBytes() is not a solution after all, which makes sense. Sorry for giving you hope :-)

Comment: No worries. It's OK. I spent the morning going through our clients' image URLs and it turns out that none of them save one had a proper crossdomain.xml file that we were listed in. ONE had the allow-all setup. And even that one gave me a mini-panic attack when it didn't load in. Then I noticed that it was going through HTTPS, and I seemed to remember something about Flash not being able to access through a different protocol than the one it, itself is accessed from. So I switched all URLs to HTTP, and it worked. Even if there is no workaround, at least you've helped me deduce the cause.

Comment: I'll have to make a push to get clients on board with the crossdomain files. In the meantime, does anybody know what people were smoking at Macromedia in the early 2000s? I mean, really, Macromedia. Come on.

Comment: One solution is to use a "proxy": You basically create a server-side script on your server, which takes an image url as a parameter in the querystring. This script retrieves the image from the url and returns the image data. This solution would work, but the loading would take a bit longer since two separate http requests are done. You could of course have the retrieved images cached on your server to speed things up.